# How do I run Panoply (from NASA GISS) on Windows 10?

Tags: modis, netcdf, panoply, lai

I am unable to run Panoply (from NASA GISS) to view NetCDF files. When I try to run it, it tells me that I need Java Runtime Environment 9, but the latest version of JAVA from the Oracle website is 8.271. How do I resolve this? I have found no documentation for the same. I want to use it to visualize MODIS Leaf Area Index data.

I am using Windows 10 (64bit).

https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download Java Runtime Environment 9 from [Oracle Download page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase9-archive-downloads.html).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone (like me) can't get the Oracle official download to work, i was able to find a direct link on GitHub, searching for the filename "jre-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin.exe"

the link is:

https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jre-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin.exe?AuthParam=1622138782_bbc2c982f49c7b24512f46bf602da91b

I installed that file and Panoply opens now (win 10).